# Microformats/schema for bibliography and citations

Tags: html, css, schema, microformats

On our website are a lot of medical articles. We often include bibliography and citations of studies there. How could I mark these citations with Microformats/schema? Is there a specific format?
Example of citations in APA:

> Sharma, P., Murthy, P., & Bharath, M. M. (2012). Chemistry, metabolism, and >toxicology of cannabis: clinical implications. Iranian journal of >psychiatry, 7(4), 149-56.
>
> Goodwin, R. S., Darwin, W. D., Chiang, C. N., Shih, M., Li, S. H., & Huestis, >M. A. (2008). Urinary elimination of 11-nor-9-carboxy-delta9->tetrahydrocannnabinol in cannabis users during continuously monitored >abstinence. Journal of analytical toxicology, 32(8), 562-9.

Citations from [this](https://www.ncsm.nl/english/thc-weed-detox) page.

Comment: Apparently the citation microformat has been added, see here: http://microformats.org/wiki/citation and you can read through the examples here http://microformats.org/wiki/citation-examples-markup . AFAIK there is no explicit way to define citations (the html tag `<cite>` may help), so you can use the Implied schema described in the examples page (bottom of page)

Comment: I tried CiteProc XHTML Output for example, but  https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ doesn't recognize microdata

Comment: Ok, hope I understood you correctly. Apparently they are called `ScholarlyArticle` you can find examples here https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/CitationPromotion and here https://www.kanzaki.com/works/2013/misc/0518-citation.html both examples are recognized in the Google testing-tool (with warnings, but I'm sure these can be prevented)